# Using Angular JS How to Retrive the Json path from UI (view side) by clicking on key

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

**I'm showing JSON object in UI by below code and its displaying very pretty. I want to get json path by clicking on key of json object.**

```
{{ dataJson | json}}
```

```
Example - 

{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A mearkup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Questions :
> 1. How to add "ng-click" to every key 
> 2. from ng-click method, How to get json path as parameter value.
> If i click on "GlossList" key, Expecting value something like "glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList"

I'm Using - Angular JS, Jsonformatter, Angular UI Bootstrap, Angular Material

Thanking helpers in advance

Comment: You need to build your own formatter. This is just plain text at the moment, you need it rendered with some form of elements `span|div|a` to add click handlers.

Comment: @kuhnroyal Thank you